# Зависает unity во время срабатывания Instantitate

Tags: c#, unity3d

### Как только ломается дерево , вместо спауна объекта зависает игра , вот код

```
public class tree : MonoBehaviour{
    private SpriteRenderer _render;
    public Color AddColorWithEnter;
    private Color _currentAddedColor;
    private Color _clearColor = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    private bool _isClear;
    public float Health = 100;
    public GameObject TreeDropedElement;


     public void OnClick()
        {
           Health -= 25;
            if(Health <= 0)
            {
                int count = Random.Range(3, 4);
                var p = transform.position;

                for (int i = 0; 1 < count; i++)
                {
                    Instantiate<GameObject>(TreeDropedElement, new Vector3(p.x, p.y + i, p.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }

            Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: Как ответили ниже, у Вас **бесконечный цикл**. И еще придирка к коду: строчка **int count = Random.Range(3, 4);** не имеет смысла, т.к. при текущих аргументах **ВСЕГДА** будет 3

Answer (score 1):

У вас там бесконечный цикл.

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < count; i++)
```

1 будет всегда меньше count и цикл будет крутиться пока не положит юнити